# macro equal to function?

Tags: c++, winapi, direct3d, directx-9, direct3d9

[FAILED macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Macro (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29)

After I read the articles above, I still not very sure whether macro is just a function or anything else. Is macro equal to function?

Example:

```
    //  Create a Direct3D 9 device.
    hr = direct3D9->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, g_hWnd, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dPP, &d3dDevice);

    //  Cout out the message to indicate the failure.
    if(FAILED(hr))
       return 0;
```

Comment: I think if I remember correctly, Macros may or may not have arguments, but all functions do. And Macros do not return anything back to the caller whereas function have to option to or not to.

Comment: I use cout << FAILED(hr) << endl; and check it display zero value on console window.

Comment: Yeah, my point exactly, You can also have `std::cout<<__DO_SOMETHING__ <<std::endl;` too.

Comment: @hagubear Both of your definitions are completely wrong.  Both functions and function-like macros may take zero or more arguments.  Macros don't technically *return* a value because they aren't functions, but they can still produce a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C and C++ a macro is a "replace this with that" type mechanism, and not at all the same as a function in a lot of senses. It can SOMETIMES be used to replace a function, but you should be very careful. Some famous "failures" in macros used as functions are as follows:

```
#define SQR(x) x * x

.... 

int x = 5;
int s = SQR(x+1);
```

This will not give 36, but (x + 1 * x + 1), which in my head makes 12 - not what you wanted. Can be fixed with using a function, or by adding extra parenthesis around `x` in the `SQR` macro.

Another "clever" use of macro:

```
#define IS_UPPER(c)  ((c) >= 'A' && (c) <= 'Z')

char *str = "Some String With a few Upper Case letters";
int uppers = 0;
while(*str) if (IS_UPPER(*str++)) uppers++;
```

Now, this will go wrong (uppers is guaranteed to be zero in this particular case, if we avoid crashing due to "missing" the end marker and keep going on...), becasue:

```
IS_UPPER(*str++)
```

translates to:

```
(*str++) >= 'A' && (*str++) <= 'Z'
```

which, if `str` is at the start of the string "Some ...", will be true for the first step, but not true for the second step since we are now pointing at the 'o' which is not less or equal to 'Z'. Using a function would work "as expected" here.

Comment: Good answer. It cannot be stressed enough to be very careful with using macros!